# using vgg16 for bounding box prediction for own dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, object-detection

After building a vgg16 based classifier. I would like to build a bounding box which bound the detected object.

I found the internet that I can do that by removing the layer after the last `Maxpool` and add some `fully connected layer`

```
flatten = vgg16.output
flatten = Flatten()(flatten)
bboxhead = Dense(128,activation="relu")(flatten)
bboxhead = Dense(64,activation="relu")(bboxhead)
bboxhead = Dense(32,activation="relu")(bboxhead)
bboxhead = Dense(4,activation="relu")(bboxhead)
box_model = Model(inputs = vgg16.input,outputs = bboxhead)
box_model.summary()
```

The model should be like this, same as that I searched.

```
   Model: "box_model"
    _________________________________________________________________
     Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
    

=================================================================
     input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
                                                                  


 block1_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
                                                                 
 block1_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 224, 224, 64)      36928     
                                                                 
 block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 112, 112, 64)      0         
                                                                 
 block2_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 112, 112, 128)     73856     
                                                                 
 block2_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 112, 112, 128)     147584    
                                                                 
 block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 56, 56, 128)       0         
                                                                 
 block3_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 56, 56, 256)       295168    
                                                                 
 block3_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
                                                                 
 block3_conv3 (Conv2D)       (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
                                                                 
 block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 28, 28, 256)       0         
                                                                 
 block4_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 28, 28, 512)       1180160   
                                                                 
 block4_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block4_conv3 (Conv2D)       (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 14, 14, 512)       0         
                                                                 
 block5_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block5_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block5_conv3 (Conv2D)       (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
                                                                 
 block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 7, 7, 512)         0         
                                                                 
 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 25088)             0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 128)               3211392   
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 64)                8256      
                                                                 
 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 32)                2080      
                                                                 
 dense_3 (Dense)             (None, 4)                 132       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 17,936,548
Trainable params: 3,221,860
Non-trainable params: 14,714,688
_________________________________________________________________
```

Then train the model

```
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

opt = Adam(1e-4)

box_model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer=opt)

steps, val_steps = train_gen.n/batch_size, val_gen.n/batch_size
num_epochs = 30

history = box_model.fit(train_gen,validation_data=val_gen,batch_size=32,epochs=30,verbose=1)
```

But I found that the last `Dense` layer has 4 dim, does not match my number of class (5). After I changed the dim to 5. It works, but I cannot train anything. The output 5-values array is not reasonable (all 0).

Or my implementation is not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: your implementation is fine, but your data is wrong.

In order to train a new output, you need new labels. The input need not change, but somehow you need to acquire the x, y, height and width of the bounding box you are trying to detect. If the data set does not provide this, you will need to label them yourself.

If you want to train on bounding box coordinates, your label needs to be bounding box coordinates. You can't keep training with the class labels of your dataset. Whatever your model is trying to learn in supervised learning, that is what you need to supply as a label.

Comment: Thanks for you reply! That's mean I should train it with the label x, y, height, width? Since my dataset is just a set of photo. I complete the classification job and now want to add a bounding box feature

Comment: If x,y is one of the corners and you calculate the height and width of the bounding box from that corner, then yes, that would work. Make sure that if you do any resizing, to take that into account in the labels.

Comment: I think I have messed up something, my dataset is the image being classified only. Is it ok? Or the Input data should be image with the coordinate so that I can train them?

Comment: In order to train a new output, you need new labels. The input need not change, but somehow you need to acquire the x, y, height, width label you mention. If the dataset does not provide this, you will need to label them yourself. Remember, an algorithm is only as good as the data its trained on. I will edit the answer to be more complete. Let me know whether this fully answers your question or if you have any additional questions.

Comment: Thanks!! I find a software call `labelImg`, which is used for labeling. At least my model is correct. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Sorry for an addition question, do I need to label all image? Or just part of them? Since I will split the image to train and validation sets using `ImageDataGenerator`

Comment: You will need to train all images you wish to use. If you want to prevent excessive human labelling, look into active learning.

Comment: Also, In the `ImageDataGenerator`, I will use `ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, validation_split=0.2,
                                   rotation_range=40, horizontal_flip=True,
                                   fill_mode='nearest')`. So can I label the original image or the rescaled image? If I need to label the rescaled image, how can I download it from Colab?

Comment: You shouldnt have to change the images, just the labels

Comment: Thank you! Then I will start to label the image!! Hope it works! :)